# Find updated GitHub forks for abandoned (old) Repository?

Tags: github, repository

When a project is abandoned, which had many forks, how can we find out which fork is actively maintained or updated? GitHub shows just a list and no filtering...

[image]

Is there any API or builtin tool to achieve that?

Answer (score 3):

These doesn't seem to be a built-in method on GitHub itself. But there are some nice tools to find & sort those Forks nicely:

- [Forked.yannick.io](http://forked.yannick.io)
- [TechGaun.github.io](https://techgaun.github.io/active-forks/)
- [GitPop2.vercel.app](http://gitpop2.herokuapp.com)